# Set service startup using DSC

Tags: powershell

DSC newbie here. The MOF file generation fails

> PSDesiredStateConfiguration\Node : The argument is null or empty.
>   Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the
>   command again. At line:13 char:5 + Node localhost + ~~~~ +
>   CategoryInfo : MetadataError: (:) [PSDesiredStateConfiguration\node],
>   ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   ArgumentIsNull,PSDesiredStateConfiguration\node Compilation errors
>   occurred while processing configuration 'SQLConfig'.
>
> Please review the errors reported in error stream and modify your
>   configuration code appropriately. At
>   C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSDesiredStateConfiguration\PSDesiredStateConfiguration.psm1:3917
>   char:5 + throw $ErrorRecord + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo :
>   InvalidOperation: (SQLConfig:String) [], InvalidOperationException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToProcessConfiguration

```
    Configuration SQLConfig {
        param(
            # Parameter help description
            [Parameter(Mandatory =$true)][string[]]$serviceConfig,
            [Parameter(Mandatory =$true)][string]$DataDrive,
            [Parameter(Mandatory =$true)][string]$LogDrive

        )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName SqlServerDsc
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node localhost
    {
        WindowsFeature Net35
        {
            Name = 'NET-Framework-Core'
            Ensure = 'Present'
        }
        WindowsFeature Net45
        {
            Name = 'NET-Framework-45-Core'
            Ensure = 'Present'
        }
        WindowsFeature Cluster
        {
            Name = 'RSAT-Clustering'
            Ensure = 'Present'
        }

        File datadrive
        {
           Type = 'Directory'
           DestinationPath = $DataDrive
           Ensure ='Present' 

        }
        File logdrive
        {
           Type = 'Directory'
           DestinationPath = $LogDrive
           Ensure ='Present' 
        }
        SqlDatabaseDefaultLocation dataPath
        {
            InstanceName = 'MSSQLSERVER'
            Path = $DataDrive
            ServerName = 'localhost'
            Type = 'Data'
            DependsOn = '[File]datadrive'
        }
        SqlDatabaseDefaultLocation logPath
        {
            InstanceName = 'MSSQLSERVER'
            Path = $LogDrive
            ServerName = 'localhost'
            Type = 'Log'
            DependsOn = '[File]logdrive'
        }
        foreach ($service in $serviceConfig) {
            ServiceSet $service
            {
                Name = $service.ServiceName
                State = $service.State
                StartupType = $service.StartupType
                Ensure = $service.Ensure
            }


        }

    }
}
  $serviceConfig=(
        @{ServiceName='MSSQLSERVER';State='Running';StartupType='Automatic';Ensure='Present'},
        @{ServiceName='SQLSERVERAGENT';State='Running';StartupType='Automatic';Ensure='Present'},
        @{ServiceName='SQLBrowser';State='Ignore';StartupType='Disabled';Ensure='Present'} ) SQLConfig -serviceConfig $serviceConfig -DataDrive "F:\Data"
    -LogDrive "H:\Log" -OutputPath "C:\dump"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several (small) issues.

First, you're configuring `Services`, not `ServiceSets`, so the resource name in the foreach loop at the bottom is incorrect.

Second, the name of the configured resource (you've got `ServiceSet $service`) needs to be a string (something more like `Service $service.ServiceName`)

Third, you've specified that the `$ServiceConfig` parameter is an array of strings, but you're supplying an array of hashtables (`HashTable[]`).  You'll want to update the configuration parameter type.

Fourth, the State value of "Ignored" isn't valid.  It should be "Running" or "Stopped"

Comment: btw, adding -Debug to the final SQLConfig call will let you step through a lot of the configuration to see where it's blowing up.  Not a silver bullet, but it will help.